It must be on one orbit, how I can fix the moon? How I can made dynamic day and night above the horizon?
I'm trying to learn HTML/JS/CSS but I can't fix it by myself.


@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0turn) translateY(-1150px) translateY(50%) rotate(1turn)
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn) translateY(-1150px) translateY(50%) rotate(0turn)
  }
}

.avatar1 {
  animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
}


/* Sun */

.avatar1 {
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  margin: calc(50% - 25px) auto 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: center -300px;
}

.avatar2 {
  animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}


/* Not Sun */

.avatar2 {
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  margin: calc(50% - 25px) auto 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: center -300px;
}


/* Контейнер */

.path {
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 960px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* Убираем прокрутку */

.noscroll {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.noscroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
<body class="noscroll">
  <div class="path">
    <div class="avatar1"><img src="sun1.png" alt="Sun" width="150" height="150"></div>
    <div class="avatar2"><img src="moon1.png" alt="Moon" width="150" height="150"></div>
  </div>
</body>



I tried to change variables like margin, transform-origin, padding or like this, but it doesn't gave any result.
What variables can I change to change moon orbit? Maybe I must paste any formulas in this vars?

Post code as a [mcve] (hint: click the brackets button <>). More importantly, there are 2 images sun1.png and moon1.png which are missing and probably neccessary for us to review with the code you posted.

What's the problem with the moon orbit such that it needs fixing?
